# How do I turn this into an AJAX function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

At the moment I have a form button which when clicked reloads the page and posts data which then runs a mySQL command, this works find but I need to show the data right away instead of refreshing again, I could reload the page after the query but that then drains my resources. Ive tried reading up on AJAX but I cant understand it (or get it to work!!)

Can anybody show me how to go about this? My current code is...

```
    elseif(isset($_POST['int1'])) {
        $interest = $_POST['int1']; 
        $qResult= mysql_query("DELETE from user_interests WHERE interest = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($interest) . "' and user_id = " . $usersClass->userID());
        if(! $qResult )
            {
              die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
            }    
    }
    if($interest1 != ''){
        print $interest1 . "<form method='post' action='#'><input type='hidden' value='".$interest1."' name='int1' id='int1'/><input type='submit' value='delete' /></form><br />";
    }
```

Comment: study and make an attempt, man! ajax in 30 seconds: http://rajshekhar.net/blog/archives/85-Rasmus-30-second-AJAX-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you're just getting into AJAX -- it will make everything work cross-browser for you.

```
$('#id_of_your_submit_button').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "where_you_put_your_php.php",
       data: "some_info=" + $('#your_input_or_whatever'),
       success: function(msg){
             $('#id_of_where_you_want_info_to_go').html(msg);
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // Tell submit button not refresh page
});
```

Then your form info (data) will be in a variable called `$_GET['some_info']` in the file you put your PHP in. `echo` out what you want to return to the document, and it will appear in the ID of where you want info to go (see names in code.)

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this page http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html ... i think this is precisely what you need now. If you have any confusion feel free to reply here.

Answer (score 0):

First: Read up on how to implement jQuery into your webpage.

Then you can use the jQuery framework to handle your ajax query.

First, create a block of code like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){
    //Your code goes here
}
?>
```

From there, create an Ajax function:

```
$('#submit_button_id').click(function(){
    jQuery.post('/webpage.php',{
        'ajax' : true
    },function(data){
        //Stuff for your page to do when your page call loads.
    },'html'
});
```

jQuery has a lot of documentation on their website so you should easily figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use the jQuery library http://www.jquery.com! It greatly simplifies working with javascript. Then give your

```
<input type='submit' value='delete' id="delete_button" />
```

Reference the jQuery library (best to put it at the very bottom of your html, right above the  tag)

Then follow it with a snippet of jQuery code like this (you will probably need to alter it to suit your needs, but I tried to get pretty close)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { // this only happens when DOM is fully loaded

    $('#delete_button').click(function(e){

        var int1Val = $('#int1').val();

        $.post("your_page.php",
            { int1: int1Val, maybeSomeOtherVar: "coolbeans value" },
            function(data) { // if your_page.php sends any response back, then this function gets called
            alert("Data loaded from server POST: " + data);
        });

        $('#someMessageDivID').text(int1Val); // to immediately display the form value somewhere

        e.preventDefault(); // I'm not sure if you need this if you also have return false below, but I always put both just to make sure the form doesn't submit on its own, because we have already done it above
        return false;

    });

});

</script>
```

You can create some really snazzy desktop-feeling web pages with AJAX, so enjoy getting to know it. I hope this helps!